# How can be validate readonly textbox to accept two digits after decimal in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have 6 textboxes. The first 5 textboxes are input and sixth textbox is for ouput to accept average value from the first 5 textboxes. The sixth textbox is readonly. I want to accept only two digits after decimal. How can i do it? Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: var x = 1.123456; //x is a number
x.toFixed(2) //returns '1.12'

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I edit code like this => $('.output').val(average).toFixed(2);. It didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$('.my_val').keyup(function () {

    var total = 0,
        count_field = 0,
        average;

    $('.my_val').each(function () {
        var val = parseFloat($(this).val(), 10);
        if (!isNaN(val)) {
            count_field += 1;
            total += val;
        }
    });

    average = (total / count_field).toFixed(2);
    $('.output').val(average);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Input1 : <input class="my_val" type="number" size="5" name="input1"><br/>
Input2 : <input class="my_val" type="number" size="5" name="input2"><br/>
Input3 : <input class="my_val" type="number" size="5" name="input3"><br/>
Input4 : <input class="my_val" type="number" size="5" name="input4"><br/>
Input5 : <input class="my_val" type="number" size="5" name="input5"><br/><br/>
Result : <input class="output" type="number" size="5" name="input6" readonly>
```

Comment: $('.my_val').keyup(function () {
    var total = 0,
        count_field = 0,
        average;

    $('.my_val').each(function () {
        var val = parseFloat($(this).val(), 0.1);
        if (!isNaN(val)) {
            count_field += 1;
            total += val;
        }
    });
    average = total / count_field;
    $('.output').val(average).toFixed(2);
}); This is my jquery. I want to accept only two digits after decimal. This output textbox is number type and readonly. I'm new to html. Please help me. You can also see on https://jsfiddle.net/laktherock/L79notux/.

Comment: Not yet ok. I want to accept two digits after decimal for output textbox. Please check for me. Thanks.

Comment: You must use parseFloat(); and then toFixed(2); please see my anwser . I have edited it.  Issue Solved?

Comment: Sorry for my fault. Your code worked for me. Thank you so much.

Comment: How can i accept the answer? I want to put text animation for textbox 6(output textbox). Text animation in and out to show voted result. Thanks.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235

Comment: @HninWaiMarSoe What kind of animation..Can you show an example?

Comment: https://codemyui.com/layers-shadow-3d-text-effect/. Like this link, i want to make text animation for textbox 6(output textbox). Thanks for your helping.

Comment: I want to set background with stars for textbox6 when textbox6 have output value and text animation for textbox6. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: you want to set background picture of a star ?

Comment: yes, your are right. Thanks

Comment: <style>
    .output {
        background-image: url('folder/imagename.png');
    }
</style> add this to your html file . Also change url to your desired image

Comment: Hello, I want to put animation for textbox6's border when textbox 1 to 5 have their input respectively. Please help me. Thanks